# API to get a list of cities and states

Tags: database, api, state, country, city

We run an app that asks users to select their country, city and state. We wanted these to be dropdowns with prepopulated values.

I went on the internet and amazingly I couldn't find a reliable source on getting countries, cities, and states/provinces through an API.

I wanted to know what is the industry standard for this since almost all e-commerces require this